# Encapsulate a plugin in another plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to ask this question through an example.

I often have a need for a similar looking dialog which is used on multiple pages.  How I currently do is shown below and is available at http://jsbin.com/aSOdOdiG/1/.  The basic steps are:

1. Add a DIV to the body either using JavaScript (which I did in this example) or directly outputting the HTML to the page.
2. Apply the jQueryUI Dialog plugin to that DIV.
3. Add a jQuery click event to the desired target element to store some particular message to the jQuery data, and open the dialog.

Now, the question.  How do I encapsulate a plugin in another plugin?  Or in other words, how do I create a plugin called "myMessageDialog" which provides the same functionality, is configured as shown below and uses the existing jQueryUI dialog plugin?

```
$('#popup1').myMessageDialog('Hello, this is my custom message for popup1.')
```

How I currently do it.....

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            div.hide-title-bar .ui-dialog-titlebar {display:none}
        </style> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){
                $('body').append('<div id="dialog-popup" title=""></div>');
                $("#dialog-popup").dialog({
                    autoOpen    : false,
                    resizable   : false,
                    height      : 300,
                    width       : 440, 
                    dialogClass : 'hide-title-bar',
                    modal       : true,
                    open: function(event, ui){
                        var $t=$(this);
                        $t.html($t.data('message'));
                    },
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            text     : 'CLOSE',
                            "class"  : 'gray',
                            click    : function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
                        }
                    ]
                });

                $('#popup1').click(function(){$("#dialog-popup").data('message','Hello, this is my custom message for popup1.').dialog("open");})

                $('#popup2').click(function(){$("#dialog-popup").data('message','Hello, again.  This is my custom message for popup2.').dialog("open");})

            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="popup1">popup1</button>
        <button id="popup2">popup2</button>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look here. http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/. But imo, you should just write a helper function to do what you are trying to do, no need for a plugin.

Comment: @Sumit.  Thank you.  What do you mean by a "helper function"?

Comment: I believe what he means is you create a function which you will pass the jquery object to and the message you want to display. The function will then take this information and run the code you have above using the parameters you passed.